# Is there a standard way to view a field $k$ as a $k[x]$ module?

Tags: modules, convention

This is a question about mathematical convention. Is there a standard way to view a field $k$ as a $k[x]$ module?

My guesses for a "most standard" candidate would be to set $x$ to be evaluated at $1$ or $0$. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think most standard is to have $x$ acting by zero. But hopefully anyone who does this will specify.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I will go for.